# ¿Cómo portar esta función hecha en C++ a C#?

Tags: c#

Hola tengo duda sobre esto bueno en mi caso a veces veo simples funciones o pequeños programas en otros lenguajes que me gustaría que fueran idénticos en C# o al menos que tuvieran la misma utilidad. En este caso estaba intentando traducir a está función a C# que está hecha en C++ y que es la siguiente:

```
#include "Erase.h"
#include <stdio.h>
/* This function will erase the current images PE header from memory preventing a successful image if dumped */


VOID Erase()
{
    _tprintf(_T("[*] Erasing"));
    DWORD OldProtect = 0;

    // Get base address of module
    char *pBaseAddr = (char*)GetModuleHandle(NULL);

    // Change memory protection
    VirtualProtect(pBaseAddr, 4096, // Assume x86 page size
        PAGE_READWRITE, &OldProtect);

    // Erase the header
    SecureZeroMemory(pBaseAddr, 4096);
}
```

Estaba editandolo para que se pareciera a  C#(lo saque por internet desde otra web):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;


namespace ConsoleApplication9
{
    class Program
    {
        [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
        public static extern IntPtr OpenProcess(int dwDesiredAccess, bool bInheritHandle, int dwProcessId);
        [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        static extern bool ReadProcessMemory(IntPtr hProcess, IntPtr lpBaseAddress, [Out] byte[] lpBuffer, int dwSize, out IntPtr lpNumberOfBytesRead);
        [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        //static extern bool WriteProcessMemory(IntPtr hProcess, IntPtr lpBaseAddress, byte[] lpBuffer, uint nSize, out UIntPtr lpNumberOfBytesWritten);
        static extern bool WriteProcessMemory(IntPtr hProcess, IntPtr lpBaseAddress, byte[] lpBuffer, int dwSize, ref int lpNumberOfBytesWritten);
        [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
        public static extern IntPtr GetModuleHandle(string lpModuleName);
        private static int ErasePEHeader() // hModule = Handle to the module, procName = Process name (eg. "notepad")
        {
            byte[] imagentheaderptr = new byte[4];
            byte[] Stub = new byte[120];
            byte[] Stub2 = new byte[0x108];
            int Out=0, Out2=0;

            IntPtr hModule = GetModuleHandle(null);

            string procName = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Name;
            procName = procName + ".exe";
            Console.WriteLine(hModule + "," + procName);

            IntPtr proc = OpenProcess(0x001F0FFF, false, System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcessesByName(procName)[0].Id);
            IntPtr IMAGE_NT_HEADER = new IntPtr((hModule.ToInt32() + 60)), out2 = IntPtr.Zero;
            ReadProcessMemory(proc, IMAGE_NT_HEADER, imagentheaderptr, 4, out out2);
            if ((WriteProcessMemory(proc, hModule, Stub, 120, ref Out) == true) && (WriteProcessMemory(proc, hModule, Stub2, 0x100, ref Out2) == true)) return Out + Out2;
            else return 0;
        }
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int a = ErasePEHeader();
            Console.WriteLine(a);
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

La excepción que me muestra:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El propósito de mi pregunta era portar el código a C# para que fuese lo más parecido posible y funcional que en C++.

Comment: DWORD esta definido como un Uint, que viene siendo un Uint de 32 bits.

usando (System.UInt32) te deberia dar.

Comment: Uint en el dword, y como incorporar la libreria stdio.h para las funciones o se puede añadir otras pienso que deba subir los errores. del programa.

Comment: a que se refiere con `images PE header`? que hace esta función en C++?

Comment: En principio la funcion c++ realiza operaciones con punteros que en C# no existen ya que el código es gestionado. Si explicas un poco que es lo que hace y para qué lo necesitas tal vez podamos darte una alternativa en C#

Comment: Simplemente borra tu cabecera, es una medida anti-reversing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bueno, obviamente el código en C# lo has obtenido de [aqui](http://www.mpgh.net/forum/showthread.php?t=743307). Tiene algunos errores, este sería el codigo correcto:

```
[DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
public static extern IntPtr OpenProcess(int dwDesiredAccess, bool bInheritHandle, int dwProcessId);
[DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
static extern bool ReadProcessMemory(IntPtr hProcess, IntPtr lpBaseAddress, [Out] byte[] lpBuffer, int dwSize, out IntPtr lpNumberOfBytesRead);
[DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
//static extern bool WriteProcessMemory(IntPtr hProcess, IntPtr lpBaseAddress, byte[] lpBuffer, uint nSize, out UIntPtr lpNumberOfBytesWritten);
static extern bool WriteProcessMemory(IntPtr hProcess, IntPtr lpBaseAddress,  byte[] lpBuffer, int dwSize, ref int lpNumberOfBytesWritten);
private int ErasePEHeader(IntPtr hModule, string procName) // hModule = Handle to the module, procName = Process name (eg. "notepad")
{
    byte[] imagentheaderptr = new byte[4];
    byte[] Stub = new byte[120];
    byte[] Stub2 = new byte[0x108];
    int Out=0, Out2=0;

    IntPtr proc = OpenProcess(0x001F0FFF, false, System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcessesByName(procName)[0].Id);
    IntPtr IMAGE_NT_HEADER = new IntPtr((hModule.ToInt32() + 60)), out2 = IntPtr.Zero;
    ReadProcessMemory(proc, IMAGE_NT_HEADER, imagentheaderptr, 4, out out2);
    if ((WriteProcessMemory(proc, hModule, Stub, 120, ref Out) == true) && (WriteProcessMemory(proc, hModule, Stub2, 0x100, ref Out2) == true)) return Out + Out2;
    else return 0;
}
```

Luego ten en cuenta que no puedes llamarlo `ErasePEHeader();`, necesitas pasarle dos parámetros (`hModule` y `procName`)

*Disclaimer: no me responsabilizo de que funcione correctamente, solo he arreglado el código que pusiste*

**Edit**

Para usar `GetModuleHandle` añade simplemente esto:

```
[DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
public static extern IntPtr GetModuleHandle(string lpModuleName);
```

En general, para usar estos métodos nativos de windows, puedes consultar aqui [pinvoke.net](http://www.pinvoke.net)

Comment: `GetModuleHandle` claro que se puede usar en C#. Mira mi edicion @OmarOmar

Comment: La excepción es clara. No está encontrando el proceso con el nombre que le estas pasando. Abre el administrador de tareas,busca el proceso que intentas buscar y copia exactamente el nombre que aparece alli

Comment: Me he ido  complicando demasiado se puede hacer igual.